# Posting data from a form using $http (REST)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, crud, angular-services

I'm trying to use Angular for CRUD operations, but I'm having some trouble sending POST requests to the server.

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller("ListingCtrl", function($scope, posts) {

    $scope.addProject = function () {
        if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
            return;
        }
        posts.create({
            title: $scope.title,
            short_description: $scope.short_description
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.short_description = '';
    };

});
```

Here's my service:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.factory('posts', [
    '$http',
    function($http){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

o.create = function(post) {
    return $http.post('linktomyliveAPI', post).success(function(data){
        o.posts.push(data);
    });
};
```

And finally, here's the view:

```
<div ng-controller="ListingCtrl">

<form ng-submit="addProject()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="title"></input>
    <input type="text" ng-model="short_description"></input>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

I've been able to successful make GET requests, but for some reason, I can't figure out POST.

My API was built using Django Rest Framework, if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: any error in the browser console?

Comment: what is the trouble that your facing? List out your console errors?

Comment: Nope. It looks like the request is just not being sent. @Aravind: There aren't any console errors. Should I add $log to my service?

Comment: error code?  if possible add a screenshot of your console!

Comment: can you debug in Inspect Element?If so then can you break point in o.posts.push(data) and hover the data if it has a returned data

Comment: yes definitely place a console.log or $log service in both success and error  callback functions

Comment: `o` is totally out of scope where you're trying to assign `o.create`. You should definitely have a console error for that ~ *"Uncaught ReferenceError: o is not defined"*

Comment: Phil, is the o object not available when that service is injected? That's what I thought I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you have added **create** method is not proper, you have to add that method on factory object

Put the create method on an object returned from factory.

In your service

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('posts', ['$http',function($http){
      var create = function(post) {
          return $http.post('linktomyliveAPI', post).success(function(data){
            o.posts.push(data);
          });
      };

      var o = {
         posts: [],

         // expose create method on factory object
         create: create
      };

      return o;
}]);
```

Hopefully these will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I had to change some server-side settings in order to get this to work.